# Store spreaded props output in single array

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for some help on a function I'm working on which, captures events from socket changes (socket.io), everything works fine but, since I'm making use of spreaded props, I'd like to store the arrays coming through in to a single array.

what I have

```
      const handlers = (...args) => {
          const result = [args];
          console.log(result);
      }

      socket.onAny(handlers);
      //socket.on('posts', handler);
```

[image: OUTPUT RESULT]

but I'd like to have the expected result:

```
Array[[{}], [{}], [{}]]
```

Comment: what's the output of `event` and `result`?

Comment: you tried [...event, ...result]?

Comment: the event is just the name of the event which you see it's console logging the event name (posts, comment), the result is the array's being passed through, so what I'd like to try is to merge all the array's that are being passed through the "args" into a single array

Comment: I see the example given wasn't entirely making sense, I've just updated it

Comment: Try declaring `const result = []` outside of `handlers`. And `result.push(args)` inside `handlers`

Comment: @adiga that did work, but now I'm facing the issue of it being logged more than once, if two arrays are being passed through the function

Comment: try `const result = args.map(arg => [arg]);`

Comment: Probably, two separate events get triggered and `handlers` is executed twice. You can debug this with some `console.log` inside the function.

Comment: @adiga I've figured that would be the cause, since socket.onMany would be the cause of it, ending up calling the function twice, would you know any work around to this to prevent it from happening or anything that would give some idea to prevent this, so that the end result would be a single array?

Comment: Not familiar with socket and node but this is the expected behavior when different events get called. The code looks like *"Every time some event you have subscribed gets triggered, call this function*". Not sure what the workaround would be. There is no *final event* here.

Comment: @adiga well I guess I've found a work around to it, well not quite but I'm getting what I want, so I'm using what you have mentioned, but I'm storing the result to a state ```setChanges(result)``` which will then return the updated output like mentioned ```[[{}], [{}], [{}]]```, so thank you for your help I really do appreciate the bit of guidance and understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the end result

```
const [changes, setChanges] = useState([]);


//Check socket changes
    useEffect(() => {
      const result = []

      const handlers = (...args) => {
        result.push(args)
        setReplies(result)
      }

      socket.onAny(handlers);

      return () => socket.offAny(handlers);
       //eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);
```

[image]